# Animating knockout template views

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, knockout.js, sammy.js

Is there a way to have transitional animations between "page" changes while using knockout for changing templates? I'm looking for something similar to [Knockback-Navigators](http://kmalakoff.github.io/knockback-navigators/examples/pnp-t_zpt_pth_ko.html#). I cant figure out a way to do this? Is there a package I can use to make this easier? Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtholla2/7E84t/17/) with the same type of binding my project uses. And a sample of my javascript here:

```
var View = function (title, templateName, data) {
var self = this;
this.title = title;
this.templateName = templateName;
this.data = data;
this.url = ko.observable('#' + templateName);
};
var test1View = {
    test: ko.observable("TEST1")
};
var test2View = {
    test: ko.observable("TEST2")
};

var viewModel = {
views: ko.observableArray([
    new View("Test 1", "test1", test1View),
    new View("Test 2", "test2", test2View)]),
    selectedView: ko.observable(),
}
//Apply knockout bindings
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

//Set up sammy url routes
Sammy(function () {
    //Handles only groups basically
    this.get('#:view', function () {
        var viewName = this.params.view;
        var tempViewObj = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.views(), function (item) {
            return item.templateName === viewName;

        });
        //set selectedView
        viewModel.selectedView(tempViewObj);
    });
}).run('#test1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways of doing this, here is one

```
ko.bindingHandlers.withFade = {    
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element);
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        var wrapper = ko.observable(observable());

        observable.subscribe(function(value) {
            var current = wrapper();
            fadeIn = function() {
                wrapper(value);
                $element.fadeIn();
            };

            if(current) {
                $element.fadeOut(fadeIn);
            } else {
                $element.hide();
                fadeIn();
            }
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { with: wrapper }, bindingContext);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7E84t/19/

You can abstract the effect like this

```
ko.transitions = {
    fade: {
        out: function(element, callback) {
            element.fadeOut(callback);
        },
        in: function(element) {
            element.fadeIn();
        }
    },
    slide: {
        out: function(element, callback) {
            element.slideUp(callback);
        },
        in: function(element) {
            element.slideDown();
        }
    }
};
```

html

```
<div data-bind="withFade: { data: selectedView, transition: ko.transitions.slide }">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7E84t/23/

Comment: Hmm you might wanna put some dispose logic in thre too, http://jsfiddle.net/7E84t/20/

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for, I'm going to try and use a sliding animation but this is a great start!

Comment: I would abstract the fadeIn, fadeOut stuff into somekind of transition type and sepcify it using the binding options somethng like http://jsfiddle.net/7E84t/22/